# Is it possible to use rack-rewrite for rewriting just POST requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-rewrite

That's it. I need to redirect just the POST requests. Something like:

```
rewrite /.*/, '/universal_POST_handler', :if => (something_cool_goes_here)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a rewriter in an application that has routing is to rewrite legacy URLs to more current URLs. Legacy URLs are URLs that were supported and that external users have come to depend on but that are no longer supported because the architecture of the application has changed.

You should use the router instead.

```
post '*path' => 'actions#universal',
  :constraints => FancyConstraint.new
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [README](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite/blob/master/README.markdown#method):

Using the `:method` option you can restrict the matching of a rule by the HTTP method of a given request.

#### redirect GETs one way

`r301 "/players", "/current_players", :method => :get`

#### and redirect POSTs another way

`r302 "/players", "/no_longer_available.html?message=No&longer&supported", :method => :post`